How to display menu by notification (Mouse Left Click) without displaying the form in Taskbar
I have a form with a NotifyIcon and a ContextMenuStrip and I want to display the menu by clicking on the notification, but unfortunately it is displayed in the taskbar. Why? I tried setting the ShowInTaskbar property to false, but it didn't work. Here is my code:
Public Class frmNotificaction
Public WithEvents MyNotify As New NotifyIcon With {.Icon = My.Resources.Icon1}
Dim MyMenu As New ContextMenuStrip
Private Sub frmNotificaction_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MyMenu.Items.Add("Item1")
    MyMenu.Items.Add("Item2")
    MyNotify.Visible = True
End Sub
Private Sub MyNoti_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyNotify.Click
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    MyMenu.Visible = Not MyMenu.Visible
End Sub
End Class


MyNotify.ContextMenuStrip = MyMenu : MyNotify.Visible = True. Read.

I did not succeed in the example you provided. (Read – @dr.null)

To hide the Form and place the notify icon, mainly you need to Me.Hide() : MyNotify.Visible = True. To restore the Form, handle the NotifyIcon.Click (or double click if you want) event to: Me.Show() : MyNotify.Visible = False. Don't forget to assign the MyMenu instance to the MyNotify.ContextMenuStrip property. Also, use the designer to drop a NotifyIcon and create a ContextMenuStrip rather than doing that in code.

Private Const GWL_HWNDPARENT As Integer = -8
        <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLongPtr", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As Integer, dwNewLong As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function
    
    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function SetWindowLong32(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As Integer, dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
        Private Shared Function SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As Integer, dwNewLong As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        If IntPtr.Size = 8 Then
            Return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong)
        Else
            Return New IntPtr(SetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong.ToInt32()))
        End If
    End Function

  Private Sub MyNotify_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyNotify.MouseClick
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
            MyMenu.Show(Cursor.Position)
            SetWindowLongPtr(MyMenu.Handle, GWL_HWNDPARENT, Handle)
        End If
 End Sub

